# JavaScript en proyecto Laravel deja de actualizarse en servidor local

Tags: laravel, reactjs

Estoy desarrollando un proyecto con Laravel y React utilizando Laravel Mix. Para el entorno utilizo el servidor de `php artisan serve` o incluso **Laragon** (con ambos sucede lo mismo).

El problema es que al poco tiempo de comenzar a escribir el código la parte escrita en JavaScript del proyecto deja de actualizarse y se queda con lo escrito anteriormente, incluso aunque borre los componentes y todos los archivos respectivos al JavaScript de React. Ya intente borrar el proyecto y volverlo a escribir y sucede siempre lo mismo. También probé con borrar el cache de la aplicación con:

```
npm cache clean --force
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
```

Para que se comprenda mejor el error:

*Componente escrito desde un principio:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button>Hola</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

*Modificación del componente:*

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <button>Cualquier otro texto</button>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

*Lo que se muestra en el servidor:*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso si borrara el componente del proyecto este seguiría apareciendo como si nada.

La parte escrita en PHP se actualiza correctamente.

Por lo tanto, cosas que ya intenté:

- Reiniciar el servidor
- Reiniciar el ordernador
- Borrar el cache
- Revisar si es un error de guardado
- Pasar de `php artisan serve` a **Laragon**

Comment: Has probado deshabilitando la caché del navegador???

Comment: @MauricioContreras Sí, ya lo hice. Persiste el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay que utilizar el siguiente comando para que los cambios se actualicen:

```
npm run watch
```